# HTML/CSS/JavaScript using JQTouch and PhoneGap to develop iPhone apps

Tags: iphone, macos, jqtouch, cordova

I would like to ask if I require a Mac for the entire process of the iPhone app development or simply to test the application and later on convert it into a format accepted by iTunes and then uploaded to the App Store.

Thanks a lot !

have a nice day :)

C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Mac (actually XCode that is available only for Mac) to sign it and compile you app before submitting it to App Store.